# New Stack Overflow navigation bar?

Tags: support, design

I came across the new Stack Overflow navigation bar recently, using a mobile browser I rarely use.

I've never seen this design on my usual browsers.

[image: Image 1]

Just to check, is this available on all browsers or sites?

**Note:** Not sure if it's only available on Stack Overflow, so I asked on Meta SE

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @PythonMaster Not famous, Puffin Browser on iOS

Comment: Maybe the updates never reached Puffin...

Comment: @PythonMaster Yea, seem like it's a new design, not sure if there's a duplicate somewhere

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We're running [a series of A/B tests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav) with a new header/topbar nav design. Congratulations, one of your devices made it into the test group.

Currently this only applies to Stack Overflow. I don't know off the top of my head if we're intending to roll it out network-wide once the tests are completed (assuming we decide to keep the new design) or not.

Comment: Does this target any specific groups of users, it's a great design, hope that I can use on my laptop too :)

Comment: @Panda Glad to hear you like it! At the moment, however, the group assignment is random.

Comment: @AdamLear The chosen is pretty amazing :) http://imgur.com/a/Fjatd